# jQuery (JavaScript) 3 > 10 = true

Tags: javascript, jquery

There seems to be some stripping issue with jQuery when retrieving integer values from input values.

My code:

```
    // Control the rating input field to only accept numeric values
    // -else set the values back to 0
    // For the highest value:
    $('.dsListItem .firstItem').keyup(function(){
        if (isNumber($(this).val()) && $(this).val() < $('.dsListItem .lastItem').val()) {
            console.log('FIRST: ' + $(this).val() + ' >>> ' + $('.dsListItem .lastItem').val());
            $(this).val($('.dsListItem .lastItem').val());
        }
    });
    // For the lowest value:
    $('.dsListItem .lastItem').keyup(function(){
        if (isNumber($(this).val()) && $(this).val() > $('.dsListItem .firstItem').val()) {
            console.log('LAST: ' + $(this).val() + ' >>> ' + $('.dsListItem .firstItem').val());
            $(this).val($('.dsListItem .firstItem').val());
        }
    });
```

Safari Inspector tells me this:

LAST: 11 >>> 10

LAST: 2 >>> 10

LAST: 1 >>> 10

Only 0 and 1 are valid. If 10 is validated as "1", it should not pass 1 > 1 either, but yet it does.

I don't get it why the console.log() print shows the correct integers but when I calculate with it the 10 get's converted into a 1.

I tried casting the number with ($(this).val() * 1), yet that didn't change anything, and anyway; the value is already checked to be a valid numeric value.

Comment: Convert your strings to integers to ensure you are getting a numeric comparison and not a string comparison.

Comment: When you get a value of input it's always a string. Use `parseInt`.

Comment: Just because it's a string that contains a valid number that doesn't mean it will be used as a number; it will still be treated as a string.

Comment: The `10` is *not* being converted to `1`.  It's being read as `"10"`.  The *string* `"2"` is greater than the string `"10"`.

Comment: @dfsq: parseInt seemed to do the trick, thanks :)

Comment: @Allendar make sure you use `parseInt($(this).val(), 10)` - pass `10` as the second parameter to make sure numbers starting with "08" or "09" will work properly.

Comment: @Pointy was going to share the same issue to take care of. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you are using numerical values then you have to cast them with a parseInt, so you'll be sure that Javascript too will be talking with numbers, and not comparing numbers to strings!

I think casting with parseInt is stronger than casting by a *1 instruction...

Comment: Practically the same as already discussed in the comments of the original post, but thanks :)

Comment: Yep... but questions need answers, not only comments... :)

Comment: Easy A for you then ^^. I'm already making tons of progress on my project now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to hear (read in this case) it!